# Boolean containing SharedPreferences not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am making a game which stores best time in a `SharedPreferences`. Here is the method executed when player wins.

```
public void victory(){
    gameOver = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Victory!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Chronometer chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    chronometer.stop();
    long elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    if (elapsedTime < sharedPreferences.getLong("best", 2147483647));{
        sharedPreferences.edit().putLong("best", elapsedTime).apply();
    }
}
```

So as you can see, it stores the time of the current game only if it's better than the best time.

Here is the code in `onCreate` which loads and displays the best time:

```
    TextView bestScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bestScore);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    if (sharedPreferences.getLong("best", 2147483647) < 2147483647){
        int min = (int) Math.floor(sharedPreferences.getLong("best", 2147483647) / 60000);
        int sec = Math.round((sharedPreferences.getLong("best", 2147483647) - min) / 1000);
        String mm = "" + min;
        String ss = "" + sec;
        if (min < 10){
            mm = "0" + min;
        }
        if (sec < 10){
            ss = "0" + sec;
        }
        String bestTime = mm + ":" + ss;
        bestScore.setText("Best:    " + bestTime);
    }
```

But, for some reason, it keeps updating the best time every time the player wins, even if the time is worse. Help please.

Comment: I think elapsedTime calculation may have issues, try to print elapsedTime value at victory time.

Comment: No, I don't think so because the "best" TextView is displaying the time of previous game correctly, but it isn't the best time.

Comment: that semicolon after if the statement in victory() method is a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a semicolon after if statement in your `victory()` method.

```
 if (elapsedTime < sharedPreferences.getLong("best", 2147483647));{
    sharedPreferences.edit().putLong("best", elapsedTime).apply();
}
```

just remove that and you are good to go.